# Install Windows 7 over Windows Vista without formatting drive or upgrading

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, installation

So I have a laptop with a 32-bit Windows Vista OS installed. I want to install Windows 7 64-bit, which is possible on this computer. However the only way to do that, is to boot off of the install disk and install on the drive over the old Windows Vista. When doing this the installer tells me that my old Windows installation will be moved to a Windows.old folder.

My question now is, if I do this type of installation, will it keep all other files in place (i.e. User folders and documents)?

Comment: Should do - although it's an extremely good time to take a backup before doing this ...

Comment: I agree.  I just am at limited resources.  I don't have anywhere to do a backup right now. Hence the question.  If I had the ability to do a backup I would just go for it after making the backup.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Backup your personal files then install the new operating system.  there is no way to install Windows 7 x64 over Windows Vista x86 without formatting the drive.  An upgrade path is not possible.

Comment: There is not a single step process to migrate from Windows XP to Windows 7 .One of the reason for <a href="http://ow.ly/iyCNO">Windows 7 Migration</a> is the architectural differences between the two OSes.

Comment: If you read my question I was talking about a migration from Windows Vista (not Windows XP) to Windows 7.  And just so everyone knows, it is possible to just install Windows 7 right on top of Windows Vista and keep the documents intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what it is supposed to do - it is supposed to leave your files intact. With windows Vista to Windows 7 migration, I would trust it.

Comment: Its not possible to upgrade Windows Vista x86 to Windows 7 x64 without a reinstallation of the operating system which will result int he personal files NOT transfering,.  **This results in the drive being formatted.**